# Installing error for SCIP in Python

Tags: python, scip

I am using python 3 on windows 7 and trying to get SCIP on it. Please see the image. I want to run a mixed integer program.

[SCIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQlpF.png)

Any further instructions will be helpful.

I downloaded SCIP 3.2.1 as seen in the image, but then I don't understand how to implement that command and where?

Comment: Please put your problem in words and mention exactly where you need help.

Comment: I did it. Please see.

Comment: So no help at all?

Comment: I am not fully familiar with SCIP, but it looks like looking through tutorial docs might solve your problem. See http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/SHELL.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySCIPOpt does not officially support Windows. There are [step-by-step instructions](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/36#issuecomment-260969876) though, in the GitHub issues.

In general, PySCIPOpt is an interface from Python to C that is built using Cython. You need to compile the interface linking to a C library of SCIP. You don't necessarily need to build this library yourself, you might want to use a precompiled one from http://scip.zib.de/#download instead.

You do need a C/C++ compiler in any case. BTW, "that command" is `make` which is a build tool for Unix that is used to compile code. It doesn'twork out of the box on Windows 7. You either need the Ubuntu Bash from Windows 10 or a Linux "emulator" like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).